# Is $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ s.t. $x_n= \frac{1}{n-2}$ not a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the following fail to qualify as a sequence?

$\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $x_n= \frac{1}{n-2}$

I ask because [*Basic Analysis*](https://www.jirka.org/ra/realanal.pdf) by Lebl gives the following definition: "A sequence (of real numbers) is a function x: $\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$." By my understanding, my example meets this definition.

Yet I also see the theorem "a convergent sequence is bounded." My example seems to be convergent (the limit equals zero), but I don't think it's bounded because of when $n = 2$.

**A follow up question here:** many of you have pointed out that my function is undefined when $ n = 2 $. But what about the sequence $ a_n = n $? In what sense is this defined as $ n \rightarrow \infty $ ? I intuitively understand there's a distinction, but it would be hard for me to rigorously express what the distinction is.

Comment: A function, is, by definition, defined on all of its domain. If you consider the asymptotic behavior of sequences it's inconsequential, but by the given definition it's not a sequence

Comment: Your function is not defined at $n=2.$ If you define it as $\infty,$ that is not in $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does **not** qualify (in regards to the definition you mentioned).

---

**Let's take a step back.** You see, the definition of a sequence changes depending on which perspective (book, course, etc.) you take. Let's define a sequence to be, say, a map from $\{1,2,3,4\}$, the index set, to the English alphabet. $\{M,A,T,H\}$ is therefore a sequence by our definition. Of course, this is very loose, but essentially, Mathematics originated from different places around the world at some point in time, but today we have an "international" language that fails to regard the exact meanings of certain words. This is because we can only have a finite amount of words in our language, and it is a *very very* small finite number. Thus, a widespread definition of the word *sequence* (which is a relatively common word) would not help to summarize the thousands that have been created across time.

---

By definition, $\{x_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ for $x_n=\frac{1}{n-2}$ is a map $M:\mathbb{N}\backslash\{2\}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, which does not follow the presented definition of a sequence $S:\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$. Thus, it can be concluded that $x_n$ is not a sequence.

---

**Edit:** I wanted to answer your follow-up question that you added. The sequence $a_n$ is "defined" as $n$ **approaches** infinity, but not **at** infinity, because infinity is not in the domain of $\mathbb{N}$ nor $\mathbb{R}$. However, we can define the word *approaches* in such a way that it means the end behavior of a function. Thus, the sequence $a_n=n$ approaches $\infty$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$. But never will a sequence with a mapping from the natural numbers to the reals have a mapping when $n=\infty$ because infinity is in neither of the domains of the image and the pre-image under the map. Approaching something is a concept that can be explained rigorously, nothing more. You don't need to know these proofs for an introduction, only know that "approaching", for now at least, means the end behavior of such sequences.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you kindly. I suppose I was uncomfortable with the notion that it is "ok" if a sequence diverges as $ n \rightarrow \infty $, yet not if it "diverges" (I understand I'm using this term sloppily) for finite $ n $. But I see now the distinction that in the former case, our sequence still constitutes a complete mapping over $ \mathbb N $ even if it diverges.

Comment: Yes, an informal sequence that diverges can be a formal sequence given by your definition in the post, as you said, because it completes a map from the index set $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, as the set of the natural numbers has a *cardinality* of a countable infinity. However, you cannot have a sequence that diverges at some finite index $n_0$. The concept of divergence is that, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that *approaches* infinity, the mapping approaches an infinitely large $\infty$ or small $-\infty$ (or it may oscillate, such as a sine wave).

Answer (score 1):

The expression $x_n = 1/(n-2)$ is not defined at $n=2$. So it cannot be considered as a function from $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ as written. However, it is defined at $n=1,3,4,\dotsc$ and you can write down the terms $-1, 1, 1/2, 1/3,\dotsc.$ So you can redefine it as $y_1=-1$, $y_2=1$ and $y_n=1/(n-1)$ for $n\geq 3$. In any case the first few terms of a sequence do not affect its limiting behavior, so $x_n$ (defined for $n\geq 3$ and $n=1$) and $y_n$ (defined for all $n\geq 1$) both have the same limit.